# how to change the background-Color on click of a button in javascript

Tags: html, css, performance

I was able to change the color of the text but i am not able to understand how to change the background color of the `p` tag. If someone can please let me know hoe to do it. Below is my `HTML` and `JS` code.

```js
function button(){
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', function onClick(event) {
  // Change text color globally
  document.body.style.color = 'red';
});
}    
button();
```

```html
<style>
        p{
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border: 1px solid black;
            height: 20px;
            width: 300px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
    
<p>Welcome To My Domain</p>



    <button id="btn">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a class to the p tag and then query that within your event listener and set its style attribute, `document.querySelector('.classname').style.backgroundColor = 'somecolor'`

```js
function button() {
  var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
  btn.addEventListener('click', function onClick(event) {
    // Change text color globally
    document.body.style.color = 'red';
    document.querySelector('.welcome').style.backgroundColor = 'black';
  });
}
button();
```

```html
<style>
  p {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>

<p class="welcome">Welcome To My Domain</p>



<button id="btn">Button</button>
```

Another way would be to toggle a class that styles your element for you. With this example add the class and style it in your css and then use the classList in javascript to toggle the class.
`document.querySelector('.className').classList.toggle('someclass')`

```js
function button() {
  var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
  btn.addEventListener('click', function onClick(event) {
    // Change text color globally
    document.querySelector('.welcome').classList.toggle('instance-change')
  });
}
button();
```

```css
.instance-change {
  color: red;
  background-color: black;
}

p {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p class="welcome">Welcome To My Domain</p>

<button id="btn">Button</button>
```

Comment: great that solved :-)